# xrdp fails to start on Ubuntu 20.04, firewall inactive - how do I fix this?

Tags: hyper-v, rdp, ubuntu-20.04, xrdp

I'm trying to connect to a Hyper-V instance of Ubuntu 20.04 via RDP.

I've installed xrdp, but it won't start:

```
 systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
 xrdp[1906]: (1906)(140210881615680)[INFO ] address [0.0.0.0] port [3389] mode 3
 xrdp[1906]: (1906)(140210881615680)[INFO ] listening to port 3389 on 0.0.0.0
 xrdp[1906]: (1906)(140210881615680)[ERROR] trans_listen_address failed
 xrdp[1906]: (1906)(140210881615680)[DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_VSOCK cid -1 port -1)
 xrdp[1906]: (1906)(140210881615680)[ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address already in use.
 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
 systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
```

Now, you might think I forgot the firewall, but it's currently disabled.

```
~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I had added the exceptions anyway for good measure. Networking works fine, I can ping/SSH to, browse from, etc.

I just can't RDP ... any ideas?

== John ==

Comment: This is an RDP server, not an RDP client.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the output of `netstat -tlpn | grep 3389`

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone...

I had the same issue and fixed by turning off the remote desktop in ubuntu 22.04

Under settings > sharing > disable the remote desktop and try to start the xrdp service again with `sudo systemctl start xrdp`